# Best module for laravel4 and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-4

We are working on new project on Laravel4 with backend MongoDb ,
I am confused as to which library i should use for backend (Lmongo , mongor or Jenssegers).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317369/best-laravel-4-mongodb-driver-bundle

Comment: https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB This one looks the best one about I think. DOing the same research myself at the minute.

Comment: Lmongo is great and lmongo-auth lib too.

Answer (score 1):

Try https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB

1. it has same eloquent and fluent query builder syntax
2. Supports all relations apart from morphTo.
3. Ability to use mysql and mongo together ( + 1 )
4. Schema class is supported too.